# NFA that accepts all numbers not divisible by 105

Tags: finite-automata

I have to create an NFA that accepts the following language L with no more than 15 states.

$L = \{a^n \mid n \geq 1$ and $n \mod105 \neq 0 \}$.

To me it seems that all multiples of 105 have the same properties:

- sum of digits is divisible by 3
- the last digit is 0 or 5

I would appreciate if someone could help me here.

Comment: Múltiples of 15 have the properties you list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hint.

$L$ is the union of the following three languages.

- $L_3=\{{a^n \mid n\ge1\text{ and }n \not=0 \mod 3}\}$,
- $L_5=\{{a^n \mid n\ge1\text{ and }n \not=0 \mod 5}\}$,
- $L_7=\{{a^n \mid n\ge1\text{ and }n \not=0 \mod 7}\}$.

Construct the DFA for the above three languages. Then combine them together.

---

**Exercise.** (It may take some time to do this exercise.) Show that no NFA with less than 15 states accepts $L$ exactly.